# USB Headset simulation

Tags: audio, usb, quality

i am trying to validate the audio quality over different USB headsets. As you might know USB headsets have variety of audio aspects like number of channels, sample rates they support, bit depths etc etc. Instead of trying to purchase so many headsets to validate my device capability, i want to have some software on my PC simulating all different parameters and record the audio getting routed to PC from my DUT. Is it possible ? Is there any software or hardware capable of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

effort exceeds potential return. Just go to your nearest electronics store and audition a few headsets.